# Nuget System.Data.SqlClient Broke My Project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I installed System.Data.SqlClient using the NuGet package manager and immediately I get this error:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.EntityFramework.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project

It wouldn't let me download new packages so I fixed that by adding this to my web config:

```
<Compilation>
    <Property Name="PlatformTarget">x86</Property>
</Compilation>
```

Then when I try to install new packages I get this error:

> An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'System.Data.SqlClient.4.1.0' from source 'Path/To/Project/packages'.

So I figured that I would just delete the Nuget package but I get

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Whenever I try to delete it.

Things I tried:

- Changing the package manager source in the Package Manager Settings
- Deleting the folder with System.Data.SqlClient.4.1.0

I am using VS 2015 on Windows 10

Does anyone have a fix for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what ended up working for me was going into the package config and deleting the entry with sqlclient.